# html menu out screen

Tags: javascript, html, css, menu

i'm use html code include 1 menu to all page and have issue menu outscreen

html body

```
<body data-smooth-scroll-offset="77">
<div id="menu"></div> 
.
.
<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#footer").load("footer.html")
        $("#menu").load("navigation-bar.html")
    })
</script>
</body>
```

[Before making a multi-page menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bqbw3.jpg)

[after the multi-page menu.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7EN06.jpg)

Comment: my leg was fine then i went out for dinner and now it hurts... Add some code pls to diagnose , at least the menu and footer divs with every css attached maybe

Comment: Please provide your CSS. If possible create a codepen or jsfiddle

Comment: my code  https://codepen.io/kittipan/pen/xqaKrN